# Does redshift need an active internet connection to work?

Tags: indicator, display, brightness

It seems redshift doesn't run without an active internet connection. If so, is there some way it could be run when there's no connection to the Internet?

Comment: It's basically a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/redshift/+bug/868904) in redshift. (Note that doesn't automatically make this off-topic)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update:** Please note that a fix is now on its way. You can either wait until it arrives in the official repositories or apply it yourself by following the advice in post #53 and on in the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/redshift/+bug/868904).

---

As Anwar pointed out, Redshift fetches its geolocation data online by default. There is a workaround, though:

### Manual configuration of geolocation data

---

**a.) Using a config file**

From the project's [homepage](http://jonls.dk/2010/10/redshift-1-6-released/):

> Redshift will look for a configuration file in “~/.config/redshift.conf”. Here is an example:
>
> ```
> ; Global settings
> [redshift]
> temp-day=5700
> temp-night=3500
> transition=1
> gamma=0.8:0.7:0.8
> location-provider=manual
> adjustment-method=vidmode
>
> ; The location provider and adjustment method settings
> ; are in their own sections.
> [manual]
> lat=55.0
> lon=12.0
>
> ; In this example screen 1 is adjusted by vidmode. Note
> ; that the numbering starts from 0, so this is actually
> ; the second screen.
> [vidmode]
> screen=1`
> ```

Look for the directory provided above. If the configuration file doesn't exist, create one and append any custom options you like.

You will want to include `location-provider=manual` and modify `lat=` and `long=` with your location. [This dialog](http://stereopsis.com/flux/map.html) will help you determine your coordinates.

---

**b.) Using command-line arguments**

Launch *Startup Applications*:

[image]

Find the *Redshift* entry in the startup app list and hit *Edit*. Under command enter the following string:

```
gtk-redshift -l LAT:LONG
```

Where LAT and LONG correspond with your coordinates. Hit save, then relog to activate *Redshift*.

Comment: I looked up for the config file. since it wasn't there i created one. setup location-provider=manual, and modify lat=8.51 & lon=76.96 set screen=0 since i use a laptop, restarted lap, still it doesn't seem working without connecting to net 
Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the output when you start recoll from the command line (CTRL + ALT +T)?. Try the following command: `redshift -v -c '~/.config/redshift.conf'`.

Comment: And if that doesn't work either, try this: `redshift -v -l 8.5:77.0`.

Comment: also did you include the section headers (i.e. `[redshift]` and `[manual]`) in your config file?

Comment: - i had included the section headers i.e. [redshift] and [manual] in the config file.
- the command redshift -v -c '~/.config/redshift.conf' doesn't work
- but the second one worked: redshift -v -l 8.5:77.0

It showed :
Location: 8.500000, 77.000000
Brightness: 1.00
Gamma: 1.000, 1.000, 1.000
Using method `randr'.
Period: Daytime
Color temperature: 6500K
(ending in)
Period: Daytime
Color temperature: 5500K

Comment: when redshift -v -l 8.5:77.0 command is run it works without internet, eventhough the redshift indicator applet wont show on screen  Is it could be helpful in solving?

Comment: ok, great, let me edit my answer with a solution that will get your indicator back

Comment: OK, see my revised answer. I don't know why the configuration file didn't work but this should do it for now. Let me know if there are any other problems.

Comment: It works fine. Thanks.  I feel it has still more bugs which needs fix.

Comment: You are very welcome. Don't hesitate to browse through the [bug list at launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/redshift) and post a bug report of your own if need be. It helps!

Answer (score 5):

The answer is yes. Redshift requires active Internet connection. It depends on `libgeoclue0` package which fetch geo location from Internet.

```
$ apt-cache depends redshift 
redshift
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: libgconf2-4
  Depends: libgeoclue0
  Depends: libglib2.0-0
  Depends: libx11-6
  Depends: libxcb-randr0
  Depends: libxcb1
  Depends: libxxf86vm1
```

You can also verify this by running redshift from terminal. The terminal will display messages like

```
Started Geoclue provider `Geoclue Master'.
Using provider `geoclue'.
According to the geoclue provider we're at: 22.36, 91.80
Using method `randr'.
```

Which suggests,  it is using Internet.

But, if you start redshift from terminal without Internet connection, the terminal will display these kinds of messages:

```
Started Geoclue provider `Geoclue Master'.
Using provider `geoclue'.
Could not get location (3 retries left): Geoclue master client has no usable Position providers.
Unable to get location from provider.
```

Comment: It showed first one. So there no way to use redshift when not connected to internet.

Comment: The first one means, you have internet connection and redshift detects it. The line `According to geoclue provider we're at ...` saying this.

Comment: @prasanna If it answer your query, can you consider accepting the answer?